# Where do I go after I found both pieces of the Masamune?

Tags: chrono-trigger

I found the two pieces of the Masamune sword in the 600 AD era. When I found the second piece, it mentioned someone's name. I assume I have to go to that person to get the sword fixed, but I don't remember what the name was and I'm not really sure what village is where anyway. Who do I have to talk to and how can I find him?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for [Melchior's Hut](http://www.chronocompendium.com/Term/Melchior's_Hut.html) in 1000 AD.

It can be found near Heckran's Cave on the center island. The same island as Medina Village!

[image]

Comment: Oh, I remember that guy. I didn't realize I would have to change time periods.

Comment: @murgatroid99 - It's Chrono Trigger.  You *always* ahve to change time periods.